# Is it possible to run a custom python script in Apache beam or google cloud dataflow

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to run one of my python scripts using GCP. I am fairly new to GCP so I don't have a lot of idea.

My python script grabs data from BigQuery and perform these tasks

Several data processing operations

Build a ML model using KDTree and few clustering algorithms

Dumping the final result to a Big Query table.

This script needs to run every night .

So far I know I can use VMs , Cloud Run, Cloud function ( not a good option for me as it will take about an hour to finish everything) . What should be the best choice for me to run this?

I came across Dataflow, but I am curious to know if it's possible to run a custom python script that can do all these things in google cloud dataflow (assuming I will have to convert everything into map-reduce format that doesn't seem easy with my code especially the ML part)?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the operations are. Beam pipelines can be written in Python and deployed on Dataflow, yes.

Comment: From your question, sounds like you want a a cloud product that runs your script, can connects to data sources, handles orchestration, etc. In that case, you could check Cloud Function or Cloud Composer.

Comment: Thanks I just edited the question. I am confused about the Dataflow part.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just need a python script to run on a single instance for a couple hours and then terminate?

You could setup a 'basic scaling' app-engine micro-service within your GCP project. The max run-time for taskqueue tasks is 24 hours when using 'basic scaling'.

> Requests can run for up to 24 hours. A basic-scaled instance can choose to handle /_ah/start and execute a program or script for many hours without returning an HTTP response code. Task queue tasks can run up to 24 hours.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed